# Frechet derivative of a special function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, frechet-derivative

Let $\Phi (u)=\tilde{M}\Big( \int_{\Omega}\frac{1}{p(x)}(|\nabla u(x)|^{p(x)}+\alpha (x)|u(x)|^{p(x)})dx\Big)$ where $u\in W^{1,p(x)}(\Omega)$ (the generalized Sobolev space), $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$, $p\in C(\overline{\Omega})$, $\alpha \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ and $\tilde{M}(t)=\int_0^t M(\xi)d\xi$ where $M:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function.

How can I show that $\Phi$ is Frechet differentiable whose differential at the point $u\in W^{1,p(x)}(\Omega)$ is $$\Phi' (u)(v)=M\Big( \int_{\Omega}\frac{1}{p(x)}(|\nabla u(x)|^{p(x)}+\alpha (x)|u(x)|^{p(x)})dx\Big)$$ $$\int_{\Omega}(|\nabla u(x)|^{p(x)-2}\nabla u(x)\nabla v(x)+\alpha (x)|u(x)|^{p(x)-2}u(x)v(x))dx,$$ for every $v\in W^{1,p(x)}(\Omega)$.

Comment: This makes no sense to me.  First, $\tilde M$ is a function of $t$, so how is $\Phi$ a function just of $u$? Second, your displayed formula on two lines is meant to be a product of those two integrals?

Comment: @TedShifrin $\Phi$ is a functional from $W^{1,p(x)}(\Omega)$ into $\mathbb{R}$ and $\tilde{M}$ is a function from $(0,\infty)$ into $\mathbb{R}$.  We take a $u\in W^{1,p(x)}(\Omega)$ and assign it an element $\tilde{M}(-)\in \mathbb{R}$. The answer of the second question is yes.

Comment: It seems to me that you should apply Leibniz integral rule. Also if I understand correctly $u(\mathbf{x})$ is a scalar and $\nabla u$ is the gradient of $u$ wrt $\mathbf{x}$. Am I correct ?

Comment: @Steph Yes, that's right. By $u\in W^{1,p(x)}(\Omega)$ I mean $u:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable and $\int_{\Omega}|u(x)|^{p(x)}dx<\infty$, and the same conditon for $|\nabla u|$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$.

Comment: @Steph Could you please tell me how I can apply  Leibniz integral rule to calculate the Frechet  derivation of $\Phi$ at $u$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define the functional
$$
\xi(u) = 
\int_{\Omega}\frac{1}{p(\mathbf{x})}
\left[ 
\| \nabla u(\mathbf{x}) \|^{p(\mathbf{x})} + 
\alpha(\mathbf{x}) u(\mathbf{x})^{p(\mathbf{x})}
\right] 
d\mathbf{x}
$$

Define now the scalar-valued function
$g(a)
=\int_0^{\xi(u+av)} M(t) dt$.

The Leibniz integral rules
implies that
$$
g'(a)
=M[\xi(u+av)] \frac{d}{da}\xi(u+av)
$$
The second product term writes
\begin{eqnarray}
(2)
&=&
\int_{\Omega}
d\mathbf{x}
\frac{1}{p}
\frac{d}{da}
\left[ 
\alpha \cdot (u+av)^{p(\mathbf{x})}
+
\| \nabla (u+av) \|^{p}  
\right] 
\end{eqnarray}
where we omit the dependence in $\mathbf{x}$.

The first term in the integrand is now computed.
Denote the scalar $c = u+av$,
and $e=c^p$.
Thus
$de 
= p c^{p-1} dc
= p c^{p-1} v da
$

The second term in the integrand is now computed.
Denote the scalar $c = u+av$,
the vector $\mathbf{e}
=\nabla [u+av]$,
and the scalar $f = \| \mathbf{e} \|^p$
It follows that
$df = p \| \mathbf{e} \|^{p-1}
d\| \mathbf{e} \|$
Since
$d\| \mathbf{e} \|^2
=2 \| \mathbf{e}\| d\| \mathbf{e} \|
=2 \mathbf{e} :d\mathbf{e}
=2 \mathbf{e} :\nabla [v] da
$
we can deduce
$df = p \| \mathbf{e} \|^{p-2}
\mathbf{e} :\nabla v da$.

These two results give
\begin{eqnarray}
(2)
&=&
\int_{\Omega}
d\mathbf{x}
\left[ 
\alpha (u+av)^{p-1}v
+
\| \nabla [u+av] \|^{p-2}
\nabla [u+av]:\nabla v
\right]
\end{eqnarray}

Because
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi'(u)(v)
&=&g'(0)\\
&=&M[\xi(u)] \frac{d}{da}\xi(u+av) \lvert_{a=0}\\
&=&M[\xi(u)] \cdot
\int_{\Omega}
\left[ 
\alpha u^{p-1}v
+
\| \nabla u \|^{p-2}
\nabla u:\nabla v
\right]
d\mathbf{x}
\end{eqnarray}
which can be arranged in the desired form

Comment: Thank you very very much for your help and complete explanation.  To me, it has so many good points to learn from. I appreciate that.

Comment: Hello dear @Steph .I have some question: why did you compute $d\| e\|^2 $? Don't we have $df=p\| e\|^{p-2}\| e\| d\| e\|=p\| e\|^{p-2}e:de$?

Comment: I don't understand this section: $df = p \| \mathbf{e} \|^{p-1}
d\| \mathbf{e} \|$
Since
$d\| \mathbf{e} \|^2
=2 \| \mathbf{e}\| d\| \mathbf{e} \|
=2 \mathbf{e} :d\mathbf{e}
=2 \mathbf{e} :\nabla [v] da
$
we can deduce 
$df = p \| \mathbf{e} \|^{p-2}
\mathbf{e} :\nabla v da$.

Comment: We write $d\| \mathbf{e} \|^2
=2 \| \mathbf{e}\| d\| \mathbf{e} \|
=2 \mathbf{e} :d\mathbf{e}
$ and deduce $ d\| \mathbf{e} \|
= (1/\| \mathbf{e}\|) \mathbf{e} :d\mathbf{e}
$.

Comment: But how can we deduce $d\| e\|=(1/\| e\|)e:de$? Would you please tell me?

Comment: simply divide by the scalar $2 \| \mathbf{e} \|$  the equality ?